# Naive example of integral with values in Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

**Naive picture:** If $X$ is a measurable space, the space $B$ of signed measures on $X$ is a Banach space. There is a natural map $f\colon X\to B$ (namely, $f(x)=\delta_x$). For any finite measure $d\mu\in B$, we have $\int_X f\, d\mu=d\mu$.

**Question:**  Is this naive picture correct for the Bochner integral? For the Pettis integral? For some other kind?

(I think that $f$ is not Bochner integrable in general.)

Comment: Thanks - but I think that [(wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_space) $B$ is dual to your space of bounded measurable functions; the dual $B^*$ is  bigger than that.

Comment: Ah, right, brainfart.

Comment: On the other hand, since the space of bounded measurable functions separates points on $B$, _if_ the integral exists in a "nice" integration theory, it must be $d\mu$.